# What are the various ways of managing multiple threads access to a single database?

Tags: java, sql, database, multithreading

One way I learned of is to use a synchronized lock on the single connection used by those threads:

```
synchronized(LOCK){
    // use connection by current thread containing
    // critical operations that may occur simultaneously.
}
```

Are there other, perhaps smarter or more efficient, ways of managing multiple threads access to a single database?

For example, use database engine's built-in support for database/table/row/etc locking? (if so, how is this done on the Java side? Is this part of the SELECT statement? or some directive given prior to using a connection?)

Comment: Use a proper framework that does connection pooling and transaction management. Each thread should have its own transaction in the ideal case.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Thank you. I am trying to understand the lower level principle. I know that nowadays almost everything is done for me (as a programmer) automagically, but if I want to delve into the principles or fundamental of how these frameworks accomplish that, how is this done?

Comment: Well, different frameworks have different ways of implementing this. You should perhaps have a look at some frameworks like Spring JDBC / Hibernate and see how things are done

Comment: All databases are designed to handle concurrency using various schemes. For example, [Postgres uses MVCC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html). It is very unusual that you need custom code to deal with concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrency management is typically viewed as a feature of the database (and therefore its responsibility), not a problem that is dealt with in client code (in this case "client" means "client of the database"). Put another way, if you start trying to manage concurrency in the client code you are essentially trying to manage the *scheduling* task of database operations, and that puts you about a quarter the way to implementing a database in your own code. That's not just a huge amount of work towards writing a database yourself, it is arguably the *hardest* part of writing a database.

With that in mind...

Databases manage multiple concurrent connections, and most databases have transactional features that allow a series of cursors and/or transactions to be created at the same time. The most common case is a database like Postgres where two transactions occurring at the same time each have their own view of the data as it was when their respective transactions were begun. If the operations conducted don't interfere with each other, then it doesn't really matter what happens inside them, they will both resolve in a way that an outside observer will always receive a consistent view of the state of the database -- whether consistent results comes at the cost of being slightly out of date (but fast) or being slow (but always accurate) is a tradeoff made in the design.

You do run into situations where you need to perform an update that will affect a large subset of the database, and you need to lock others out and force them to wait until your special operation is complete (otherwise a string of transaction failures may result). Most databases permit locks on schemas, tables, columns, rows, etc. and have a variety of lock types: insert, select, update, etc. as well as mechanisms to temporarily suspend integrity checks and apply them all at the end of a locking transaction, and a number of other features that assist with the rare edge cases where you really do need to do some magical things to the database.

How is does this appear in client code? It depends on if you write stored procedures within the database (so that some complex operation is hidden behind a function call), write your queries out by hand in your client code, use a hybrid approach, and whether or not your database has a large set of pre-built functions to take care of most of the obvious cases where you need things like locking. The *most common case*, however, is that *you don't need to think about concurrency* for the vast majority of your database operations.

You will need to establish connections. Most often this is done by creating a pool of connections (worker threads/processes) shared by the main application, and the pool library will provide a queue or message-box abstraction that will serialize your requests to the connection pool. Sometimes a direct-connect (1 client == 1 connection) approach is totally sufficient (this is actually sufficient in the vast majority of cases, but we all *love* to show of how awesome we are with pooling...). Sometimes you will have several different kinds of applications connecting to a single database at once.

Consider an application server that feeds native desktop clients, a mobile application service that provides read-only access to the database, a document exporting utility, a warehousing or POS system that deals in product transaction data, and a web reporting interface for that system. An even more familiar case (for me) is game servers that all access and update a central data source, while web forums and "armory" type reporting interfaces access the same data from elsewhere. There is no way to deal with concurrency in the client code across multiple types of clients. Thank goodness these features are built-in to most databases already!

Comment: Thank you very much. I could not have expected a better and more complete answer than this. +1 & accepting.

Comment: @JaySouper Glad I could shine some light on that (and also glad to see my explanation did not put you to sleep -- brevity is not my strongest point). I'll run through here later and plug some links in to the things I mentioned. The Postgres MVCC link in Adomar's comment is very interesting if you want to see how Postgres deals with this underneath.